# How to integrate a constant in Redirection Header of php

Tags: php, html, redirect, constants

It is defined in a `config.php` file

```
define("url_money", "www.himanshu1234.net63.net/MoneyManager/");
```

it is included in some other file like

```
include_once './config.php';
```

and used like this

```
<?php
    header('Location: '.url_money.'login.php');  
}
?>
```

there is some problem in it but unable to sort out.. !!

Comment: Is there any error at all? Even if you check logs/turn on errors? What's the result of echoing `url_money`?

Comment: I actually am testing this on a live server. and have put on these, so, I won't be able to produce logs !!

Comment: it is a free server.. so won't be able to take logs

Comment: Is there any alternate way, what I am trying to do!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
define("url_money", "www.himanshu1234.net63.net/MoneyManager/");
```

to

```
define("url_money", "http://www.himanshu1234.net63.net/MoneyManager/");
```

When you define some link without `http://` then it will be treated as relative link. So you were actually redirected to `/www.himanshu1234.net63.net/MoneyManager/`

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue like this, and I made a stupid mistake. Then I saw

> It is important to notice that header() must be called before any actual output is sent

So, please double-check whether there is any echo or printf, etc... costed me a few hours some years ago!

Comment: No bro.. no echo.. Is there any alternate way, what I am trying to do!!

Comment: An alternative would be doing this with JavaScript, it would still be a redirect, but not a php redirect. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript I've copied the code into a testfile on my server, and it worked immediately. Could you provide more code, please?